# Is 圧力 countable?

Tags: grammar, counters, nouns

Consider the following sentence (emphasis mine):

> ひょっとしたら僕が​**圧力の一つや二つをかけられて**​いることも知っているのかもしれない。

The bolded part is kind of confusing me. I get that 圧力をかけられる means "to be pressured" or "to have pressure applied [to one]", but I don't understand how you can have 一つや二つの圧力, since 圧力 seems like an uncountable noun.

Is this just an unusal way of saying 僕が一度や二度圧力をかけられた ("[someone] pressured me once or twice")?

Comment: Where is this sentence coming from?

Comment: @Ataraxia It's a professionally-published piece of Japanese fiction (a light novel, for what it's worth).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

圧力 here means "pressure to do something (or not do something)". E.g.: 論文を発表しないよう圧力を受けた (I was pressured to not publish my paper).

There could be multiple, distinct ways of applying such pressure, like freezing one's account AND threatening to kill him, etc. That's why he says 「一つや二つ」.